# Contact Form 7 diferent contact identification for same site

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

Hi I have a WP site with a contact form 7 plugin, this site has several sections and each of these sections has a link to the contact page, what I need is a way of knowing in which section the user was when it click to go to the contact page to know how to respond to your message

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a `$_GET` parameter to the page that has the contact form on it.

See here:
https://contactform7.com/getting-default-values-from-the-context/

Comment: Additionally, you can use the Conditional Fields plugin to basically change what the form looks like, based on the parameter you pass. https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-conditional-fields/